# How do I make UISearchBar select from the filtered results?

Tags: xcode, uisearchbar

I hope someone can help me.  I have a search bar implemented and it does filter the results the way it's supposed to.  The problem is that when I select from the filtered results, it selects from the original array.   From what I've read, one approach would be to remove all the items from the filtered array and ADD the selected items.  The other approach would be to remove all the items that don't match the search criteria.

The problem is that I don't know how to do this - despite hours of searching.  I would be grateful for any help or pointers in the right direction.

**Here is my code:**

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    categories = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"Other",
                  @"Breakfast",
                  @"Chemist",
                  @"Computer",
                  @"Dinner",
                  @"Drinks",
                  @"Entertainment",
                  @"Fuel",
                  @"Groceries",
                  @"Haircut",
                  @"Hotel",
                  @"Internet",
                  @"Laundry",
                  @"Lunch",
                  @"Meals",
                  @"Medical",
                  @"Parking",
                  @"Snacks",
                  @"Stationery",
                  @"Taxis",
                  @"Telephone",
                  @"Transport",
                  @"Travel Taxes",
                  nil];

    self.allCatgeories = categories;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

and

```
(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    self.searchResults = [self.allCatgeories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below, it works fine for me:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
[self.filteredInboxItems removeAllObjects];
/*
 Search the main list for products whose type matches the scope (if selected) and whose name matches searchText; add items that match to the filtered array.
 */
for (NSNumber *id in self.inboxItemDAO.inboxItemIDs)
{
    NSDictionary *inboxItem = [self.inboxItemDAO getInboxItem:id];
    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"bla bla 1"])
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [[inboxItem objectForKey:@"Subject"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [self.filteredInboxItems addObject:inboxItem];
        }
    }
    else if ([scope isEqualToString:@"bla bla2"])
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [[inboxItem objectForKey:@"Sender"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [self.filteredInboxItems addObject:inboxItem];
        }
    }
    else if ([scope isEqualToString:@"bla bla 3"])
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [[inboxItem objectForKey:@"Action"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [self.filteredInboxItems addObject:inboxItem];
        }
    }
}
```

}